# numpy distance matrix, iterate index in value order without both [i,j] and [j,i]

Tags: python, numpy

```py
distance_matrix = np.array([[0,2,3,2],
                            [2,0,5,8],
                            [3,5,0,4],
                            [2,8,4,0]])


sorted_numpy_idx = np.argsort(distance_matrix, axis=None)
idx_to_iterate = np.column_stack(np.unravel_index(sorted_numpy_idx[::], distance_matrix.shape))
print(idx_to_iterate)

[[0 0]  [1 1]  [2 2]  [3 3]  [0 1]  [0 3]  [1 0]  [3 0]  [0 2]  [2 0] [2 3]  [3 2]  [1 2]  [2 1]  [1 3]  [3 1]]
```

row and columns are ordered with location A -> D, so:

The distance between A and A is `distance_matrix[0:0]`

The distance between A and B is `distance_matrix[0:1]`

The distance between B and A is `distance_matrix[1:0]`

- Locations distance between itself (A,A) will always be 0 and this will be the only value that is 0.
- The reverse distance will always be the same ie. A->B == B->A, but there will be duplicate distance values between different location pairs, i.e. in this example A->B = 2, A->D = 2.
- The order of rows and columns is important as I use this index to reference other data.

I want to iterate the index pairs based on value order (as above), but excluding 0 vals (less important) and avoiding 'duplicates' such as [0,1] and [1,0] since they both reference the same location pair (A->B and B->A), I just need either of these, but not both.

Is there a way to thin the `idx_to_iterate` using numpy, or is this a better way to structure this data? I still need to hold the 'duplicates' in both orders for other functions.

Comment: The easiest way would be to check if the pair  `(i,j)` or `(j,i)` has already been computed I guess.

Comment: For now, I have zero'd the `[j,i]` version of the location pairs, sliced `idx_to_iterate`[(count of zeros):,:] to skip the unwanted index pairs (all those that now have a value of 0) and updated other functions to reference `[i,j]`.